# Prove that $F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ is smooth

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, convergence-divergence

Let $f$ be a smooth function, for which $f(0)=0=f'(0)$. Prove that for $x\in\mathbb  R$ and $$F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right),$$

$F(x) \in \mathbb R$ and $F$ is smooth.

I wanted to prove first that $F$ is differentiable. $F(0)$ is convergent. I don't really have a clue about the rest of the task.

Comment: As a first step, note that $|f(u)| \leq Cu^2$ for small enough $|u|$. Conclude that the series for $F$ converges uniformly on compact intervals. Try to repeat a similar game with the derivatives of $f(x/n)$.